# Input Group in combination with span: style problems using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am facing a style problem.
So this is my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Site Name</span>
    <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" placeholder="Additional Info">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-addon">URl</span>
    <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" placeholder="Additional Info">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Number</span>
    <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" placeholder="Additional Info">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Desc. or Comment</span>
    <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" placeholder="Additional Info">
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
```

I have different long names in my span tag. The problem is that my input fields are not in a column. I want them to be among themselves. Can u tell me what how to get the style i want.

Comment: does someone has an idea how to make this in bootstrap 4 or 5

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you trying to use? 4 of 5?

Comment: What do you mean by "my input fields are not in a column. I want them to be among themselves" by that last part?

Comment: FWIW your markup is invalid HTML here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved my problem with some custom css.

Create style.css and dont forget to link it in your html code!

that css worked for me:

```
.input-group-addon {
    min-width:80px;
    text-align:left !important;
}
```

Comment: Most of the time having ` !important;` in CSS outside a library like Bootstrap means something is "wrong" or some understanding of that library (Bootstrap here) can help do this without those.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate everything per Bootstrap styles. You don't have your items layed out in rows/columns. The following example would be with Bootstrap 4.

Use the **Full Page** option when viewing the snippet.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <span class="input-group-addon col-sm-12 col-md-3">Site Name</span>
      <input type="text" id="msg" class="form-control col-sm-12 col-md-9" name="msg" placeholder="Additional Info">
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-5">
      <span class="input-group-addon col-sm-12 col-md-3">URL</span>
      <input type="text" id="msg" class="form-control col-sm-12 col-md-9" name="msg" placeholder="Additional Info">
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-5">
      <span class="input-group-addon col-sm-12 col-md-3">Number</span>
      <input type="text" id="msg" class="form-control col-sm-12 col-md-9" name="msg" placeholder="Additional Info">
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-5">
      <span class="input-group-addon col-sm-12 col-md-3">Desc. or Comment</span>
      <input type="text" id="msg" class="form-control col-sm-12 col-md-9" name="msg" placeholder="Additional Info">
    </div>    
  </form>  
</div>
```

Comment: Your code as presented breaks the input groups style

Comment: Can you explain what that means? I don't have any breaks (`<br>`) in my code. Please clarify.

Comment: Do you know what a Bootstrap `input-group` is? it breaks that as in "it does not work with your"

Comment: Execute the OP sample snippet to get a visual difference

Answer (score 0):

I admit I am guessing a bit as to your intent here that you mean to make the input group start labels have a similar width so that is what I attempt here.

Your input group prefix text is already left so we can simply leverage the Bootstrap grid column classes for this.  Here I used `col-3` to force a 3/12 of a width for the `input-group-text` using in Bootstrap 5.  You can try other values such as `col-2` or `col-4` etc.

Things I did:

- Used Bootstrap 5
- Changed your ID attributes to be unique so that the HTML is valid
- Changed your `name` attributes to match the id I had changed it to
- Removed the `<br>` markup as it seemed to not be needed - if you need more space you can increase `mb-3` to `mb-5` or give the next item `mt-3` or some such.
- Changed the `placeholder` attribute text to better illustrate which field we were using

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-text col-3">Site Name</span>
    <input id="site-name" type="text" class="form-control" name="site-name" placeholder="Name here">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <label class="input-group-text col-3">URI</label>
    <input id="url" type="text" class="form-control" name="url" placeholder="URL here">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-text col-3">Number</span>
    <input id="site-number" type="text" class="form-control" name="site-number" placeholder="Number Info">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-text col-3">Desc. or Comment</span>
    <input id="site-desc" type="text" class="form-control" name="site-desc" placeholder="Comment Info">
  </div>
</form>
```